# Where should I set context path for Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, java, tomcat9

My regular question about Tomcat. [Tomcat docs about `<Context>`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html).

> It is NOT recommended to place  elements directly in the
>   server.xml file.

But

> This attribute **must only be used** when statically defining a Context in
>   server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from
>   the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.
>
> Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, this attribute
>   must not be set unless either the docBase is not located under the
>   Host's appBase or both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false. If
>   this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.

Questions:

1) Where should I set my context `path` (Without ROOT.war and ROOT.xml) (I must in `server.xml`, but it is not recommended)

2) What is double deployment and when do it happen?

3) If I set my context `path` to `""` and if I set `docBase` in `/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/mysite.dom/mysite.xml` in `catalina.out` is next entries:

```
17-Aug-2018 10:24:25.883 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [] in deployment descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/mp.org/mp.xml] has been ignored
17-Aug-2018 10:24:25.890 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/var/www/ModularPlatform/target/web/mp] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
```

But I can adress by this path - it is work.

3.1 Why do it work?

3.2 Why do tomcat trying to ignoring this?

4) Also in `catalina.out` is next entrie too:

```
17-Aug-2018 10:24:26.047 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/www/mysite/target/web/ROOT]
```

Why do tomcat create the ROOT directory?

I have Tomcat 9.0.10.

Thank you for patience.

P.S. Sorry for my english.